# Game page navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to build an simple game using XNA 4.0 on Windows Phone.
On my project, I will have 2 page, `MenuScreen` and `GameplayScreen`. In Silverlight, I can add new page easily And I can use `NavigationService.Navigate("/blablabla.xaml")` to move to another page on my project.
How can I do that on XNA? There are no page options when I want to add new item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because XNA hasn't the concept of page. If you need to use Silverlight you can easily create a project that use XNA and Silverlight, merging their features.
Otherwise, if you can't use Silverlight in your project, you have to implement your `MenuScreen` class that will manage what you need (buttons and detecting touches) and then, when you want to launch the `GameplayScreen`, you simply call your class that manage your game (like a sprite manager or a model manager), hiding the menu class or deactivating it.
Of course every class has to inherit from `DrawableGameComponent`.